# How do I get XPath at character offset?

Tags: xml, xpath

I use xmlstarlet to validate XML files.

When it fails I will get the numeric position of the error. But I want XPath instead. Is there a tool to convert position to XPath?

In the case of a well-formed XML file there should always be an XPath that corresponds to that position.

**QUESTION:** On the Linux command line: given a line+character position inside an XML file how do I programmatically get the corresponding XPath?

**Example:** My schema says apples must be red or green. But I have a brown apple. So I get an error at position "2.27".

```
$ cat schema.xsd
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="fruit">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="apples">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="green"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="red"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="bananas"/>
                <xs:element name="cherries"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
✓

$ cat badfruit.xml
<fruit>
    <apples>brown</apples>
    <bananas>yellow</bananas>
    <cherries>red</cherries>
</fruit>
✓

$ xmlstarlet validate --well-formed badfruit.xml
badfruit.xml - valid
✓

$ xmlstarlet validate --err --xsd schema.xsd badfruit.xml
badfruit.xml:2.27: Element 'apples': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'brown' is not an element of the set {'green', 'red'}.
badfruit.xml - invalid

$ xmlstarlet elements badfruit.xml
fruit
fruit/apples
fruit/bananas
fruit/cherries
✓
```

**WANTED:** A command that does this:

```
$ magiccommand "badfruit.xml:2.27"
/fruit/apples
```

Is there a tool for that?

**Background info:** My real life example is a little more complicated. I'm dealing with a 10k lines file where XML element names have been reused at several different hierarchy levels. So if validation fails with "Element 'x' invalid", then this doesn't mean much to me and because "x" might appear at several different levels. And these are generated by different Java code. So knowing exactly what XPath is affected would be very helpful to me. At the moment I just reopen the file in a graphical XML editor (Notepad++ with XML-tools plugin) and revalidate inside there. Then it'll jump straight to the error position. And current XPath under cursor will be in bottom left corner in status bar. But I'd like to avoid that extra step and stay on command line.

#### Update 2023-02-06. Screenshot of equivalent feature inside NPP

Here's two screenshots.

Notepad++ with the [XML tools](https://github.com/morbac/xmltools) plugin displays XPath at cursor in the lower left corner of the screen. So I basically want that feature but not inside Notepad++ but on the command line.

Cursor at 2.27 shows XPath `/fruit`
[image: NPP cursor at 2.27]

So xmlstarlet outputs `2.27` as the position of error but inside Notepad++ you actually have to be at position `2.26` to get the XPath I want.

Cursor at 2.27 shows XPath `/fruit/apples`
[image: NPP cursor at 2.26]

Comment: Interesting. A validator probably could easily internally keep track of a depth "stack" ("XPath", but just the simple hierarchical path, no conditions nor element index?) and report the path location on error. With the position number, separate tools could read the XML file again and construct such a path. But sounds like there should be a validating XML-editor which also displays the path of the current cursor location in the hierarchy? Can imagine some high-end XML-editors support such, but don't know for sure.

Comment: It's been a while but does it work at your end if you use (one of the  two) `ln2xpath()` from my answer and run the following: `xmlf='badfruit.xml'; xsdf='schema.xsd'; lncol=$(xmlstarlet format "${xmlf}" | xmlstarlet validate --stop --err --xsd "${xsdf}" /dev/stdin 2>&1 | awk -F':' 'NR==1{print $2; exit;}'); lnno="${lncol%.*}"; colno="${lncol#*.}"; xmlstarlet format "${xmlf}" | ln2xpath /dev/stdin "${lnno}"`

Answer (score 1):

Building the error element xpath out of the error message and then using [xml2xpath](https://github.com/mluis7/xml2xpath) to get the xpath could be an option

```
echo "badfruit.xml:2.27: Element 'apples': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'brown' is not an element of the set {'green', 'red'}." | sed -rne "s@.* Element '([^']+)': .*value '([^']+)' .*@//\1[.='\2']@p"
```

Result

```
//apples[.='brown']
```

Getting its XPath with [xml2xpath](https://github.com/mluis7/xml2xpath)

```
xml2xpath.sh -a -s "//apples[.='brown']" -x tmp.xml
```

Result (redacted)

```
...
XPath expressions found: 1 (absolute, unique elements, use -r to override)
================================================================================ (2022-12-28 12:51:34 -03)

/fruit/apples[1]
```

Given this XML

```
<fruit>
    <apples>brown</apples>
    <bananas>yellow</bananas>
    <cherries>red</cherries>
    <apples>brown</apples>
</fruit>
```

It would return

```
/fruit/apples[1]
/fruit/apples[2]
```

**Note**: `xml2xpath` requires `xmllint` but it's accessible on most Linux distros.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know that script. Thanks! But that script seems to have a bunch of rough edges still. I can't get this to work consistently on my system. Using Windows with Cygwin and/or WSL. So not quite Linux-like enough.

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff thanks for the feedback. I'm the script author so feel free to file an issue there and I'll see if it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Using column numbers can be tricky as error and warning messages may
report the column of start / end of the (1) opening tag, (2) closing
tag, (3) node name, or (4) node value.
But since you want XPath expressions formatting the XML file can make
things simpler.

Run the XML file through a formatter which prints max. one element tag
per line with attributes on the same line, then use XSLT with an XML
parser which maintains line numbers.
Using Saxon's [`lineNumber`](https://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.5/extensions.html)
extension an XPath expression can be extracted given a line number.
It is supported by the Saxon 6.5.5 XSLT 1.0 processor and, via
[`libexslt`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxslt), [xsltproc](/questions/tagged/xsltproc) and [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)
(and probably other XSLT processors).
The more recent Saxon-PE and Saxon-EE processors (since version 9.9.1)
[support](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!extensions/attributes/line-numbering)
both line and column numbers. So does the
[SAX2](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/Locator.html)
API.

Some some quick tests showed that Saxon 6.5.5 processed a 106MB
spreadsheet XML file containing 2 million lines as expected.
`libexslt`'s
[`saxon:line-number()`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxslt/-/blob/master/libexslt/saxon.c#L230),
however, never returned values above 65535, thus limiting the range of
usable line numbers. That limit is likely memory-related, it isn't
configurable by `xsltproc` or `xmlstarlet` command-line options
(both are [libxml2](/questions/tagged/libxml2)-based).

---

This is the XSLT transform for Saxon 6.5.5.

File: `ln2xpath.xsl`

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:saxon="http://icl.com/saxon" 
  extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
>
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:param name="pathname"/>
  <xsl:param name="lines"/><!-- list of line numbers -->
  <xsl:param name="delim" select="'&#9;'"/>
  <xsl:param name="newline" select="'&#10;'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat('# File: ',$pathname,$newline)"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="saxon:tokenize($lines,' ')">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('# Line: ',.,$newline)"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$root//*[saxon:line-number() = current()]">

        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name(),'['
          ,1 + count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])
          ,']')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="attribute::*">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(
            '@',name(),$delim,normalize-space(),$newline
          )"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

where:

- the outermost `xsl:for-each` iterates over line numbers passed
  as arguments using the
  [`saxon:tokenize()`](https://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.5/extensions.html#tokenize)
  extension function;
  it also changes the [current node](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#dt-current-node) so `$root`
  is saved for later
- the 2nd `xsl:for-each` processes element nodes whose
  [`saxon:line-number()`](https://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.5/extensions.html#linenumber)
  matches the [current](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-current) line number from `$lines`
- the 3rd `xsl:for-each` builds an XPath expression from elements on
  the `ancestor-or-self` [axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#axes)
- the 4th `xsl:for-each` lists attributes, one per line, with values in
  [normalized](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#function-normalize-space) form

Example:

```sh
ln2xpath() {
  # Arguments:
  # $1 pathname of file output by `xmlstarlet format file.xml`
  # $2 list of line numbers (min. 1)

  java -jar saxon655.jar -l "${1}" ln2xpath.xsl pathname="${1}" lines="${2:?line numbers?}"
}

xmlstarlet format /usr/share/*/xslt/docbook/common/db-common.xsl | 
ln2xpath /dev/stdin '17 53 132 54321'
```

- the `-l` option enables line numbering
- `${2:?…}` [expands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) the 2nd positional
  parameter, or causes the shell to bzzzt and fail if missing

Output:

```
# File: /dev/stdin
# Line: 17
/xsl:stylesheet[1]
@exclude-result-prefixes        db str msg
@version        1.0

# Line: 53
/xsl:stylesheet[1]/xsl:key[3]
@name   db.biblio.label.key
@match  biblioentry[@id and @xreflabel] | bibliomixed[@id and @xreflabel] | db:biblioentry[@xml:id and @xreflabel] | db:bibliomixed[@xml:id and @xreflabel]
@use    string(@xreflabel)

# Line: 132
/xsl:stylesheet[1]/xsl:template[4]/xsl:choose[1]/xsl:when[2]/xsl:variable[1]
@name   prev
@select $node/preceding::*[name(.) = name($node)][1]

# Line: 54321
```

---

This is the equivalent `xmlstarlet` version (max. 65535 lines input).

```sh
# shellcheck shell=sh disable=SC2016
ln2xpath() {
  xmlstarlet select --text -t \
    --var lines -o "${2:?wot, no line numbers?}" -b \
    --var delim -o "$(printf '\t')" -b \
    --var root='/' \
    -o '# File: ' -f -n \
    -m 'str:tokenize($lines)' \
      -o '# Line: ' -v '.' -n \
      -m '$root//*[saxon:line-number() = current()]' \
        -m 'ancestor-or-self::*' \
          --var pos='1 + count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])' \
          -v 'concat("/",name(),"[",$pos,"]")' \
        -b \
        -n \
        -m 'attribute::*' \
          -v 'concat("@",name(),$delim,normalize-space())' \
          -n \
        -b \
        -n \
  "${1}"
}
```